# How to define Vue's 3 emit

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looking for if it is possible to define the type of the emits. In a SFC in a script setup we can do ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits)):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
// runtime
const emit = defineEmits(['change', 'update'])

// type-based
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'change', id: number): void
  (e: 'update', value: string): void
}>()
</script>
```

Since I'm looking for is a way to define the same thing but in a render function based:

```js
export const ComponentA = defineComponent({
  props: {...},
  setup() {
    const emit = defineEmits<{
      (e: 'change', id: number): void
      (e: 'update', value: string): void
    }>()
  }
})
```

unfortunately I get the following error `defineEmits() is a compiler-hint helper that is only usable inside <script setup> of a single file component.`.

Is there a way to define the events being fired and their types?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't declare emits from within `setup()`, but you can use the [`emits` option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#emits) alongside the `setup()` hook, and access the emits from the context argument's `emit` property (i.e., via the 2nd argument of `setup()`):

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export const ComponentA = defineComponent({
    
  emits: {
    change: (id: number) => true,
    update: (value: string) => true,
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    emit('change', 'foo')
    // @ts-expect-error
    emit('update', 100)
    // ok
    emit('change', 100)
    // ok
    emit('update', 'x')
  }
})
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4QZN)

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

You said it yourself:

> ... is compiler-hint helper ... **only usable inside  of a single file component**

Comment: Basically there isn't any other way to type the emits in a render function based component?

Comment: Correct. Use SFC for that. Its only compiler *suger*.